# Dynamic Add ItemTemplate for GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am dynamically adding a template filed to a dynamically added gridview control.

I add the template filed like this:

```
 TemplateField TmpCol = new TemplateField();
                        TmpCol.HeaderText = "";
                        TmpCol.ShowHeader = false;
                        rpt.Columns.Add(TmpCol);
                        TmpCol.ItemTemplate = new TemplateHandler();
```

Class:

```
public class TemplateHandler : ITemplate
{
    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        CheckBox cmd = new CheckBox();
        cmd.ID = "ckSkill";
        cmd.Text = --  want to give data text filed here or pass a custom  text

        container.Controls.Add(cmd);
    }

}
```

**So the check box in template field i want to give the container value.**

Just like we did in aspx pages like

```
 <%# Eval("demo") %>
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: use container.DataItem.Eval("ColumnName")

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani How to use this container.DataItem.Eval("ColumnName")  in code

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani See my code- all the controls, template fields are dynamic

Comment: You are right, you need to set headerText while adding TemplateFields to make sure you can determine which column to bind, and DataItem is a property of container object that you can access in code as well

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani How to use DataItem in Template handler and how?. Can you please post the code where i can access  dataitem in InstantiateIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to modify the handler like this to make it work

```
   public class TemplateHandler : ITemplate
{
    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        CheckBox cmd = new CheckBox();
        cmd.ID = "ckSkill";
        // cmd.Text = "tets";

        cmd.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.BindData);

        //cmd.Click += new EventHandler(Dynamic_Method);
        container.Controls.Add(cmd);
    }

    public void BindData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox l = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow container = (GridViewRow)l.NamingContainer;

        l.Text = ((TableNameClass)container.DataItem).SkillText; // ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)["SkillText"].ToString();

    }

    protected void Dynamic_Method(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((CheckBox)sender).Text = "Hellooooo";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While dynamically creating templated fields, you need to set some property (ex. header tex) that you can use to determine the column name. Once you are done with that, you can use following code to set data.

```
DataRowView drv;
drv = ((DataRowView) container.DataItem);
cmd.Text = drv["lastname"].ToString();
```

For more detailed explaination, [use this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301573.aspx)
Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can give container value by the handling row data bound event of gridview.
Like.

```
protected void grdData_RowDataBound(object sender, C1GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    string sText = Convert.ToString(((System.Data.DataRowView)             (e.Row.DataItem)).Row.ItemArray[0]); 

    CheckBox chkText = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("ckSkill");
    chkText.Text = sText.ToString();
 }
```